# MapFragment as Expandable Child List Item redrawing on scroll and open/collapse

Tags: android, expandablelistview, supportmapfragment

I am using an `ExpandableListView` with one of the child list view items as a `SupportMapFragment` which is added dynamically in `getChildView()` of my custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter` class as:

```
FragmentManager fm = fragment.getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment)
                .commit();
    }
    GoogleMap googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
```

and my list item layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

I have taken care that the list item layout is **inflated only once** in `getChildView()`
The issue I am facing with this is that whenever any group item is opened or collapsed or if the `ExpandableListView` is scrolled the **map whites out** (zoom controls and Google logo do not go) and is drawn again.
Like this:

[image: Issue screen shot]

What can possibly be done to avoid this???
Any suggestions are welcomed...
Thanks in advance.

**[Edit]**
I tried using ViewHolder pattern too...  but that didn't help much.

Comment: Its as though the `MapView` is being destroyed and recreated which is meant to happen. I don't think there is a way to override this as its the default behaviour of the `ExpandableListView`. I could be wrong however.

Comment: @DiscoS2 Thank you..  I could finally solve my problem by getting rid of the list view and using a RelativeLayout instead.